# Insert Image in Excel Sheet Using PowerShell at Specific Position

Tags: excel, powershell

```
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application -Property @{

 Visible = $true

 DisplayAlerts = $false

}

$wb = $xl.WorkBooks.Add()

$sh = $wb.Sheets.Item(‘Sheet1’)

$sh.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\xyz.jpg",1,0,0,0,400,200)
```

Using this code I am able to insert picture in excel sheet but it always puts the picture at "A1" position.

Is there any way to insert picture at selected row,column location using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A picture isn't in any cell. It's in a different layer on top of the cells.
You are telling it to be at 0,0 with your code. If you do this:

```bsh
$sh.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\xyz.jpg",1,0,300,300,400,200)
```

you will insert it a 300, 300.